# Check that RouteTable.Routes entry has been removed

Tags: c#, iis, routes

I have to drop a C# patch into the App_Code of a live website (patch code below) to reconfigure the routing table

```
 // Note: RouteTable needs System.Web.dll
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes["my-custom-route"]);
```

Once I have restarted IIS, is there a way that I can check that the my-custom-route has been removed successfully from the website?

Comment: in my opinion in iis there is no option to check custom routs is removed. if you want to achieve this requirement you need to write code for this.